# Copy data from worksheet to html file to mail

Tags: vba, excel

I gather the data from different Excel sheets and paste the table and content in one sheet and then push that to html file to Outlook.

While pasting the data from the sheet to html file, it is calculating the number of columns in which the data is present.

For Example in one sheet I have pasted text which is around 500 characters on the very first row. On the next row I have pasted a 5*10 table. While copying data to html file it is calculating only 10 columns and copying the data which is in yellow in screenshot.

How do I copy all the data from Excel to html file.

If I use Sheet.UsedRange then on the basis of column it is copying data.

[image]

Code:

```
     Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Dim htmlContent
    Dim RangetoHTML
    Dim lastColumn
    Dim lastRow
    Dim LastCol
    Dim TempFile As String

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (ws.Name  "Signature" And ws.Name  "URL") Then
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange

    lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 20))

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=ws.Name, _
         Source:=ws.UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")



    htmlContent = htmlContent & RangetoHTML
    'You can also use a sheet name
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange
    End If
    Next ws

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "sagarwal4@dow.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = htmlContent
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: is the range always the same?

Comment: Please share some code!

Comment: Could you add your code so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this instead:

```
Dim lastCell As Excel.Range

Set lastCell = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,  MatchCase:=False)

Range("A1", lastCell).Copy

'// Rest of code here ....
```